# Change direction of mat-slide-toggle

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want a `mat-slide-toggle` to simply change the direction from right-to-left to left-to-right.

I don't mean the text in relation to the switch (which can be handled by the `labelPosition` property), but the actual switch itself being on the right when off and on the left when on. I could invert the underlying value and then swap all the styles between the checked and unchecked state, but I was hoping for a simpler way.

Is there something I'm missing? I don't think I see anything in the API documentation. I thought about just using CSS to invert the positioning via a transformation (just mirror it around the halfway point for example), but I'm not sure if that would work, or how to use it (I'm not skilled in CSS).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to post the code whatever you had tried related your question, So we understand clearly to solve your problem.

Comment: [This example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rh9mfz?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.css) shows how you can override the CSS so it _appears_ to be off when at the right, and on when at the left. It's not ideal though as 1. it uses `/deep/` which will soon be deprecated. 2. any changes material make to CSS classes will result in the CSS overrides needing to change. 3. the `checked` property of `mat-slide-toggle` will be false when on and true when off (as on is now off and vice versa) 4. I don't think this solution will work specifying a `color` using `ThemePallette`

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add `dir="rtl"` or `dir="ltr"` to the wrapper div.

```html
<div dir="rtl">
  <mat-slide-toggle>إسحبني!</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>

<div dir="ltr">
  <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

For the [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhrqke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.html)

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working.. Could you provide an example ?

Comment: I hope this example will help you... @RaphaëlBalet

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhrqke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.html

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to achieve it is by adding css to mat-slide-toggle tag or it's class.

- example :

  **mat-slide-toggle{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }**